# Hw to substitute one specific Widget with another One once OnPressed is performed

Tags: flutter

I have 2 specific Widget which the first One has a RaisedButton which should be clicked and the widget with the RaisedButton will be substitute with another one.
this is my code:

```
Widget FundsWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Devi acquistare dei crediti per poter vedere i Post di ${widget.user.name}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            elevation: 10,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Acquista Crediti'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (_) => PostGrid(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

and this is called into the main build method, once RaisedButton is clicked, should be substited by another one

```
Widget PostGrid() {
    return Container(
      height: 291,
      child: GridView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: widget.user.imageUrl.length + 1,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index == widget.user.imageUrl.length) {}
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                actions: [
                  Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
                  Text(widget.user.name),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

that at the moment is not into the build method.
how I can perform that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use setState method inside your onPresesd and change a bool in it.
and check that bool to set suitable widget like below pattern:

```
class Test2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test2State createState() => _Test2State();
}

class _Test2State extends State<Test2> {
  bool boolName = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child:boolName ?FontWeight:PostGrid ));
  }

  Widget FundsWidget() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Devi acquistare dei crediti per poter vedere i Post di ${widget.user.name}',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            elevation: 10,
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Text('Acquista Crediti'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                boolName = false;
              });
            }
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget PostGrid() {
    return Container(
      height: 291,
      child: GridView.builder(
        controller: controller,
        itemCount: widget.user.imageUrl.length + 1,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (index == widget.user.imageUrl.length) {}
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                actions: [
                  Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
                  Text(widget.user.name),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            child: Card(
              elevation: 5,
              child: Image.asset(widget.user.imageUrl),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```